# Why Django is encapsulating all the content inside the Body Tag

Tags: html, django, django-views, django-templates

I have a problem that I am reproducing with a simple example.

No matter what I do I do always have a page with my content inside a body (js, footer, etc) like the image attached.

Can anyone help me to figure this out? Thank you.

If I remove the body tag from base.html, django include a body tag itself that encapsulates the remaining content.

base.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock content %}
</body>

<footer>
    <h3>This is the footer</h3>
</footer>

<script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'bootstrap-4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}" ></script>

</html>
```

home.html:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
<div>
    <h1>This is the home body</h1>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

The render result:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a django issue.

The *html* tag can only have a *head* and *body* tag inside it. Your *footer* and *script* should go inside the *body*.

Your web browser have detected that the structure of your document is not valid and have corrected it.

If you check the HTML source code of your page (instead of using the dev tools), you will see that the template is rendered as you write it.

So move all your page content in the *body* tag.

Comment: You are right. I was thinking in a structure like header body footer at the same level and not inside the body. So javascript also need to be included before body close. I was mistaken. Thank you.